# Trying to show message box when something is submit with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

Im using CSS to show error and sucess messages like this:

**My html&php:**

```
echo '<span class="ms sucess">Sucess</span>';
echo '<span class="ms error">Error.</span>';
```

**My css** to format the messages:

```
.error{background:#ffa3a3 url(../ico/no.png) 7px no-repeat; border-color:#900; color:#900;}
.sucess{background:#A6FFBC url(../ico/ok.png) 7px no-repeat; border-color:#090; color:#090;}
```

And then I use like this:

```
if($email == $result['email'] && $pass == $result['pass'])
        {
        $_SESSION['result'] = $result; 
        header('Location:'index.php');
        echo '<span class="ms no">Wrong password.</span>';
    }
```

And it works fine,

But now im trying to show the messages in a center box with jQuery and with a ajax loader gif when the forms are submited, but Im still starting learn jQuery and Im not having sucess doing this.

**Im trying like this**:

```
 if($email == $result['email'] && $pass == $result['pass'])
            {
            $_SESSION['result'] = $result; 
            header('Location:'index.php');
             echo '<div class="loadsistem">echo '<span class="ms no">Wrong password.</span>'<img src="img/loader.gif" /></div>';
        }
```

And than I have this **jQuery**:

```
document.getElementById('#loadsistem').ready(function() {
    $('.loadsistem').fadeOut("fast",function(){
        $('.dialog').fadeOut("fast");   
    }); 
});
```

Somebody there with jQuery exprience can give a little help?

Comment: For one, you're using `getElementById('loadsistem')` but your `<div>` doesn't have an `id` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, but still nothing is happening!

Comment: (1)Is this supposed to look like this:  echo '<div class="loadsistem">echo '<span class="ms no">Wrong password.</span>'<img src="img/loader.gif" /></div>';

                                                                               (2)Can you indicate if a JS error is being returned (check error console of browser) and post the whole generated html and js (pref in jsfiddle)?

Comment: Also: document.getElementById('#loadsistem'), change that to $("#loadsistem");
The "#" is to indicate 'id' for jquery or css, you can't use in getElementById... The DOT (.loadsistem, .dialog) represent css class, do you have dom elements with class 'dialog'?

Comment: Which element is loadsistem??

Comment: Its my div class where i show the message!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty confused about your code. If your trying to have those messages show up when the user submits the form, your jquery should look more like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submitbuttonid').click(function(){
       $('.loadsistem').fadeOut("fast");
    });     
});
```

Where #submitbuttonid is the id of your submit button on your form. Also, I didnt see a dialog  class in your code, so I removed the fadeOut function that was calling it. I would try this and see if it works and go from there. Hope this helps.